# Are static variables volatile?

Tags: static, rust, volatile

I have this Rust program:

```
use std::{thread, time};

static mut c:bool = false;

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        // call some FFI program which sets up signals
        c = false;
        while !c {
            thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(10));
        }
    }
}
```

I give the pointer to `c` to some FFI program who sets up signals which change `c`. How can I go sure the the compiler doesn't eliminate the `while` loop as it assumes `c` is never going to change?

C has a `volatile` keyword which tells the compiler not to optimize in these examples. How can I tell the Rust compiler the same thing?

(I tried to read the LLVM IR code but was not able to figure out how to understand it).

Comment: bummer, forgot the `mut` keyword which is of course crucial in this context. Fixed it and also added the comment where I would call FFI

Comment: [This reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/40ewem/what_is_the_rust_equivalent_for_cs_volatile/) might be of some help.

Answer (score 2):

No, static variables are not volatile.

The proper solution within Rust is to use [`AtomicBool`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicBool.html). The following example (from [`std::sync::atomic`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/index.html#examples)) is quite similar to what you want to do:

```
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicUsize, Ordering};
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let spinlock = Arc::new(AtomicUsize::new(1));

    let spinlock_clone = spinlock.clone();
    let thread = thread::spawn(move|| {
        spinlock_clone.store(0, Ordering::SeqCst);
    });

    // Wait for the other thread to release the lock
    while spinlock.load(Ordering::SeqCst) != 0 {}

    if let Err(panic) = thread.join() {
        println!("Thread had an error: {:?}", panic);
    }
}
```

You could do it in this way via some callback from the signal handler into Rust.

There are also unsafe functions [`std::ptr::read_volatile`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.read_volatile.html) and [`std::ptr::write_volatile`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.write_volatile.html), which can be used to directly access memory. Normally these should only be used for accessing hardware registers or for implementing safe abstractions.

Comment: Most notably, `std::ptr::read_volatile` does NOT setup memory barriers, so does NOT work for cross-thread signalling as the hardware might not do the necessary sync'ing.

Comment: thank you, I have tried with only `AtomicBool` and this won't work, I guess the `Arc` around it is crucial? Also: how would I give the pointer to the actual bool to C?